# Convert SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

Добрый день помогите разобраться в конвертации календаря, когда конвертирую календарь и текущее время он возвращает на день больше, а месяц и год все правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код который использую для конвертации даты, месяца и года:

```
GregorianCalendar cse =  new GregorianCalendar();
cse.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PUBDATE)))); // дата новости
cse.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateString = fmt.format(cse.getTime());
Log.d("DMC6", "dateString  " + dateString );
holder.textPubData.setText(dateString);
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужно добавить часовой пояс (TimeZone).

Comment: Так у вас в коде: `cse.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Спасибо  Vartlok).

Comment: @Vartlok оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде есть строчка:

```
cse.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Если посмотреть в [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add-int-int-):

> Adds the specified (signed) amount of time to the given calendar
>   field, based on the calendar's rules.

Т.е. ваш код сам добавляет к значению один день, который вам и мешает.